# imcompatible types, cannot import springrunner class

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin

```
@ExtendWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes= CommunityApplication.class)
```

it said

> Incompatible types. Found: 'java.lang.Class<org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner>', required: 'java.lang.Class<? extends org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.Extension>[]'

then I added codes in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
```

then it said

> Package 'junit:junit' can be upgraded to version '4.13.2'

Comment: try to use @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class), and delete the @SpringBootTest

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misusing the annotations.

**@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)**
This one is used just to enable spring boot features. (@Autowire, @mockbean). It is the bridge between unit tests and spring boot test features used for testing. When you need to test those Spring Boot associated elements, you use this annotation.

**@SpringBootTest**
This one is used for integration testing. It loads a complete application context which is used for end-to-end testing.

You used not mix up these 2 annotations.